# How to write multi line input in Django

Tags: django

I am making a very basic BBS system (like blog) in Django.

I've made a form where user can type in their content which I call 'body' and I declare it as 
folowing in the forms.py:

```
body = forms.CharField(widget= forms.Textarea, label="body",required=True)
```

and in the models.py,

```
body = models.TextField()
```

I somehow can't seem to be able to write multi line texts...

To sum it up,

I can write multiple lines into my form like:

Hello this is test

This is sample test2

333333

But When I submit it,
I only see

Hello this is test This is sample test2 333333

---

Comment: Your code seems to be working and produces the value `u'asdasdsa\r\n\r\n\r\nasdsads\r\n\r\nasdasd'` in your textarea. Are you sure you're seeing it right ir do you have a problem with displaying it in your templates?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The error happened when display it.

Textarea uses `cr\lf` to break lines. That is how it would
be saved into db. But html will ignore `cr\lf` you need to replace `cr\lf` with `<br>` or `<p>`

A template tag  [linebreaks](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#linebreaks) can help you, when you display it.

```
 {{ value|linebreaks }}
```

Comment: Hi,

I am also looking for the same, I have a model with text field and also corresponding admin class, I have no clue where to put this ??? do we need to override the html and create a template for it???

Comment: @LokeshSanapalli - in the html template - you are essentially appending '|linebreaks' to what you already had so that linebreaks appear similarly to how they were originally input